# biblatex: Cite commands with the same author prints authors name twice

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm using `biblatex 1.4b`, and Biber 0.9. However, I think the problem
is with my settings, not with the versions of those programs.

I'm trying to cite a single author, and produce their name, followed
by the dates of two papers, using the `authoryear-ibid` style, and
`natbib` compatability. Here's my `biblatex` preamble:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

What I want is for the following command:
`The works by \citet{Blau81, Blau88} ...`
to produce:
`The works by Blau (1981; 1988) ...`
however, what I'm getting is:
`The works by Blau (1981); Blau (1988)...`

I know that `biblatex` knows they're the same author, since in the
bibliography they fall under the same name (i.e. after the first
instance of the name, there's just a dash instead of the name)

What am I doing wrong here? I've also tried it with the commands `\cite`
and `\cites`, and neither produces what I want.

(crossposted with comp.text.tex)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting. Another hint: Always provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/3240). Doing so you increase the chance to get valuable answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want the `authoryear-icomp` citation style, instead of `authoryear-ibid`.  From the `biblatex` manual: "[`authoryear-comp` is a] compact variant of the `authoryear` style which prints the author only once if subsequent references passed to a single citation command share the same author." (p. 61)  The `authoryear-icomp` style combines `-comp` and `-ibid`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to switching to the `authoryear-icomp` style, you might also want to change the delimiter for "compressed" multiple citations to a semicolon (instead of the default comma) plus an interword space:

```
\renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
```

EDIT: The above tweak is especially useful if you suppress the page prefix for citation postnotes (with `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}`, `\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}`), resulting in e.g.

> Sengupta and Tipple 2007, 2009

instead of

> Sengupta and Tipple 2007, p. 2009

This way it is clear that "2009" is the page cited* and not another works by the same author(s) as in

> Sengupta and Tipple 2007; 2009

`*` [Here's](http://usj.sagepub.com/content/44/10/2009.abstract) the link to the abstract of the actual article starting at p. 2009.